# derived variables in R

Tags: r

Dataset

```
id salary  slaray_updated
 1   2500    4000
 2   3500    3000
 3   1000    1500
```

I am trying to derive a new column called "status" based on condition, if slaray > salary_updated then "TRUE" else "FALSE"

```
id salary  slaray_updated  status 
 1   2500    4000           FALSE
 2   3500    3000           TRUE
 3   1000    1500           FALSE
```

Comment: Do you mean to do `dataset$status <- dataset$salary > dataset$salary_updated`

Comment: yes Evan Friedland..